# How can local variable be changed by statement variable?

Tags: c++, variables, scope

I am a complete beginner, learning from youtube videos. And i am confused in this little concept here.
The value of sum is '0' outside the scope of for loop. then we change it inside the scope of for loop. how come it is not still '0' when we print it outside the for loop.
I know it's a stupid question. but from what i read , it should not change outside the scope of for loop ?
I just want to learn.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n =10 , sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
       sum += i;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Scopes are not always fully independent from each other. The loop sees `sum` and `n`. If it couldn't see `sum`, it would have failed to compile. Generally, declare as locally as you can so that you aren't spraying visibility all over the place.

Comment: yogesh, `sum` has a _scope_ and _lifetime_ from `int ... sum=0;` up to the `}` after `return 0;`.

Comment: I don't know if learning from youtube videos is a good approach, unless you have run into a particular good one :) Books are usually reviewed so they tend to be better (if sometimes a bit outdated). From the inventor of c++ : https://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html, and then there is https://www.learncpp.com/ where you can take it step by step too

Answer (score 0):

This is just how lexical scopes work.

`sum` is defined in a scope enclosing the body of the for loop so it is in scope in the body of the for loop. It's just like the way in which "global variables" in some file -- variables defined at file scope -- are visible from functions in the file.

It's the other direction this doesn't work in i.e. if there was some local variable `foo` declared in the body of the for loop you could not access the value of `foo` in the enclosing scope after the for loop terminates.